# How to do this aggregation in spring data mongo db?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How to do this aggregation in Spring Data MongoDB?

```
db.order.aggregate([
    { $match: { quantity: { $gt:1 } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$giftCard", count: { $sum:1 } } }
])
```

Comment: Could you look at this link - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation
It contains some examples related with aggregation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the sample code for the query mentioned in the question.

Please change the getMongoConnection() with your way of getting the mongoOperations object. I have just added my code at the bottom for your reference.

```
public Boolean getOrderGiftCardCount(Integer quantity) {

        MongoOperations mongoOperations = getMongoConnection();

        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("quantity").gt(quantity));
        GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("giftCard").sum("giftCard").as("count");

        Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group);

        AggregationResults<Order> orderAggregate = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate,
                "order", Order.class);

        if (orderAggregate != null) {
            System.out.println("Output ====>" + orderAggregate.getRawResults().get("result"));
            System.out.println("Output ====>" + orderAggregate.getRawResults().toMap());
        }

        return true;

    }
```

**My connection method for reference:-**

```
public MongoOperations getMongoConnection() {

        return (MongoOperations) new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class)
                .getBean("mongoTemplate");
    }
```

**Spring data version used:-**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Sample output:-**

```
Output ====>[ { "_id" : 2.0 , "count" : 2.0} , { "_id" : 1.0 , "count" : 2.0}]
```

Answer (score 5):

The following aggregation operation is a Spring Data MongoDB equivalent:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(where("quantity").gt(1)),
    group("giftCard").count().as("count")
);

AggregationResults<OrderCount> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    agg, "order", OrderCount.class
);
List<OrderCount> orderCount = results.getMappedResults();
```